# How to pass a test fixture to a helper function in C++ GTest

Tags: c++, methods, visibility, googletest, fixtures

I have a protected static method in my test fixture I wish to call from a helper function, instead of from the unit test function itself.

```
class Fixture
{
  ...
protected:
    static void fixture_func( int foo );
};

void helper_func( int bar ) {
  Fixture::fixture_func( bar );
}

TEST_F( Fixture, example_test ) {
  fixture_func( 0 );  //Line 1: This is how you would normally call the method
  
  helper_func( 0 );  //Line 2: This is how I need to call the method
}
```

When I try Line 2, I obviously get an error that the method is 'inaccessible' because its a protected method within `fixture`. How can I somehow pass the test fixture to `helper_func`, or else put `fixture_func` within the scope of `helper_func`?

If you're wondering, simply calling `fixture func` from the unit test itself is not an option because I am designing a test framework meant to simplify the use of fixture_func for a particular purpose. I also do not have the ability to make non-trivial changes to `fixture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot call** `protected` nor `private` methods from outside of a class, no matter if that method is `static` or if the calling function is C-style one.

In any case, you would need the class scope `Fixture::` before `fixture_func`:

```
void helper_func( int bar ) {
  Fixture::fixture_func( bar );
}
```

You need to make `fixture_func` become `public` somehow, you may try:

```
class FixtureExpanded : public Fixture { };
void helper_func( int bar ) {
  FixtureExpanded::fixture_func( bar );
}
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to put put in the scope for my call to `fixture_func` in the question, but I did try that in my code. I like you're idea of making my entire test framework class a derivative of Fixture, I think that will solve my problem. Thanks!